# Partial differentiation of tensors

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, differentiation, calculus

We know that  $∂x^ρ /∂x^μ = δ^ρ_μ$

Τhen, $∂x_ρ /∂x^μ = η_{ρμ}$
Should be correct, right?

Similarly,
$\frac{∂x_ρ} {∂x_μ} = δ^μ_ρ$

Also, if
$x'^μ = e^α x^μ $, then
$∂'_μ$ should be $e^α ∂_μ$

I am new to this topic and I don't know if I am in the right direction.
Can someone please help clarify?

Comment: I can delete the post if it's not up to the requirements of posting questions

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/616574

Comment: @Nihar Karve no it's not a duplicate but it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I think the big thing here is that "taking a derivative relative to a lowered index" is a bit of a strange concept, since the coordinates are typically represented with raised indices, by convention.

I'm not the downvoter, but I presume that's the reason for the downvote.  I generally think downvoting without a comment or a close vote is a pretty rude thing to do.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer as I said I am new to this and there are many such questions.

Comment: I don't think the question is out of line.  I will say that the first thing and the second thing you have above are correct (in special relativity only), but are generally the only two that anyone would ever write.

Comment: For example, @Jerry Schirmer I have a question as follows :.     $\frac{∂x^2} {∂x^μ}$ where  
  $x^2=η_{μν}x^μx^ν$

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer what about the fourth thing?

Comment: Second derivatives are zero, because all derivatives of the kroneker delta are zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128591/discussion-between-korra-and-jerry-schirmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also new in this topic and a high school student, my go on this is as:

$1.$ $\displaystyle \frac {\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \delta_{\mu}^{\rho} $ when we say that $x^\nu$ is component of vector.

---

$2.$  $\displaystyle \frac {\partial \vec x_{\rho}}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \Gamma^{\nu}_{\rho \mu} \ \ \vec x_{\nu} \ $ where $ \ \displaystyle \vec x_{\nu} \ $ is Basis vectors  as lower index show covariance.

Moreover,  $\displaystyle \Gamma^{\nu}_{\rho \mu} =  \frac {\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{\mu} \partial x^{\rho}} \cdot \partial_{j} \ g^{j\nu} $

(I may be wrong in this part cause we generally not use lowered index for components, but if it is the case : $\displaystyle \frac {\partial  x_{\rho}}{\partial x^{\mu}} =   g_{\rho \nu} \frac {\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} = g_{\rho \nu} \ \delta^{\nu}_{\mu} = g_{\rho \mu}  $)

---

$3.$ $\displaystyle \widetilde {x^{\mu}} = e^{\alpha} x^{\mu} $ This shows us the contravariant  old to new transform, using inverse Jacobian. Thus $\displaystyle e^{\alpha} \widetilde {\partial_{\mu}} = \partial_{\mu} $

Comment: Thanks for your input! I had actually resolved this question in a chatroom. Also , the last one is $e^{-\alpha}$